# Modeling vs. Modelling tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Already there are two tags for this ("Modeling" and "Modelling").  Should we, very early on, decide on one tag and try to edit posts in order to keep consistency and better searching?

Answer (score 3):

We can alway merge tags down the road when one becomes dominant.  That's possible for the administrators to do.  I think trying to moderate every tag at the beginning is probably not going to work effectively.

*Edit:*

Just read the section in here on this subject: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/.  In that case, I vote for "Modeling".  Let's try to keep it clean on that.

What does this tag even signify?  On our site, it seems so general as to be almost meaningless.  A huge percentage of questions could be tagged with that.

Comment: I agree with you on "Modeling" - I just wanted to bring it up.  (I also agree that it's somewhat vague in a statistics sense... but I'm sure it'll end up getting used, so I'd rather there be one, consistently vague tag than two ;) )

Answer (score 2):

It is basically a question AmE versus BrE; since the SE tags boxes has while-typing suggestions, simple the first will win if we just let it go.

Comment: There are, currently, 2 of each.  That was why I brought it up - if we "move" two, so there are 4 of the same, this will probably never happen again.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a tag synonym so:

> modelling -> modeling

Answer (score 0):

I re-tagged all modelling tags to modeling. There were 3x as much with 1 l and it is nice to have it consistent now the public beta started.

If off course somebody has a good reason for wanting the double l version, we can retag them all at once.

Comment: At the moment I do not see any reason either way. So, I think single l is fine.